# Why must I wrap a number to call its methods?

Tags: javascript

```
js> (5).toString(2)
101

js> 5.toString(2)  
js: "<stdin>", line 53: missing ; before statement
js: 5.toString(2)
js: ..........^
js>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript assumes (bizarrely) that a number followed by a dot means the dot is a decimal point.  This is counter-intuitive, but at least it's reliable.

You have several choices as to how you deal with this:

```
(5).toString(2); #1
5..toString(2);  #2
5.0.toString(2); #3
5 .toString(2);  #4
```

Stackoverflow's syntax highlighter shows you that, in #2 and #3, the first dot is considered to be part of the number and the second to be the operator.  In #4, we can see that the space tells the parser that the number has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Because without the parentheses, the dot in `5.toString()` is interpreted as a decimal point. Without parentheses, the interpreter interprets that sequence of characters as a floating point literal.

Comment: Out of curisity, do `5 .toString(2)`, `5.0.toString(2)` and `5..toString(2)` work?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, numbers may be floating point, so `5.0` is a valid number. When you use `5.toString`, it looks like `toString` is the fractional part of the number. Javascript's parser does not handle this case.

Some other languages (such as Ruby) handle this differently.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter tries to parse the `.` as a decimal point first, thus it expects `toString` to be a numeral.  Note that the following works since it already has received the decimal:

```
js> 5.0.toString(2); // -> "101"
```